# AdMob banner is not showing

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense

Sometimes the admob banner does'nt show in my app. It shows only white color instead of ads, but if I click on the banner then the advertisement opens in the browser. I checked it on 3 phones.

It looks like this:
[image]

On the emulator, ads are shown without problems.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` I have necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and

```
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-#################~###########" />
```

The admob layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-################/############/string>
```

This is the `MainActivity.class`

```
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-#################~###########");
        adBanner();
    }

    private void adBanner() {
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

The account Admob is active and I see that the number of clicks and impressions is increasing.
The app in the play google is active too.
What is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you are using *test ids provided on docs* and not real ids when testing or your account will get banned.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir Yes, I know, thx. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Code looks fine to me so is the manifest. I think you should only worry if the testing ad is shown correctly visible. or try some sort of VPN. As i am thinking its not the issue of the code.